# JavaScript regular expression currency decimal only

Tags: javascript, regex

My knowledge of regex is very weak. So far I have manage to create an expression that verifies if a string is an integer or not. The issues is that I only want decimal numbers NO WHOLE numbers at all.

**Regex:**

```
"currency": {
                    "regex": /^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d\d)?)|(\.\d\d))\s*$/,
                    "alertText": "* Not a valid decimal number."
                },
```

**Example**

```
valid:
45.00

invalid:
$45.00
45
$45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
/^\s*[+-]?(\d+\.\d\d)\s*$/
```

If you want to allow `.50` change `\d+` to `\d*`.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of decimal points can be larger than 2 then you can use:

```
^\s*[+-]?\d*\.\d+\s*$
```

This will handle 10.50, .50, 10.5123456 etc

Comment: Oops, good point. Changed from ^\s*[+-]?\d*\.\d*\s*$ to ^\s*[+-]?\d*\.\d+\s*$